# How to make a non-resizable desktop app look the same on all types of pc resolutions

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-8, desktop-application, screen-resolution

Please help me out guys I spent so much time on this project and the results are shocking,

I developed a desktop software using NetBeans(with javafx 8)  and scene builder on a 1920 × 1080 resolution screen(Laptop Full-hd) and it looked pretty fine on that resolution.

Now the problem is that when I try to open that software on another pc with a different resolution(1366 × 768), it kinda enlarge the software and make it look realy bad.

Please help me out this issue guys.

Thanks in advance.

**Note: My software is developed in a way that it can not be resized, the sizes are fixed**.

Comment: Without providing any code would be very difficult for everybody to help you

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could [edit], rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: Respectively: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Yeah, obviously: when you tune your application for one specific fixed screen size - then other screen sizes will give you trouble. You have to step back and first clarify your requirements. **You** have to decide how you want to go about different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed UI in any platform you have to develop using the lowest resolution possible especially if you want to distribute your software publicly otherwise it is better to develop a responsive UI. Sln : lower the resolution of your screen and resize your UI. PS. That's a temporary solution.

Comment: Thanks Amos I'll try to develop it on the lowest resolution